# Blazor FieldChanged Event not firing for custom components

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I have a project (.NET Core 3.1.9) with a `FieldListener` component nested inside of an EditForm. It subscribes to the FieldChanged event like so:

```cs
@using Microsoft.JSInterop 
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] EditContext CurrentEditContext { get; set; } //get cascaded edit context
    private TestModel Model { get => CurrentEditContext != null ? (TestModel)CurrentEditContext.Model : new TestModel(); } //adds a getter to directly get the Model

    protected override void OnInitialized() //called on component creation
    {
        CurrentEditContext.OnFieldChanged += FieldChanged;
    }

    private void FieldChanged(object sender, FieldChangedEventArgs args) //called whenever a form field changes
    {
        JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("console.log", "FieldChanged Triggered. Model is: " + Model);
    }

}
```

This works fine for a regular InputText components but doesn't fire for a custom component like this:

```cs
<input type="text" class="form-control" @bind-value="text" />

@code {
    [Parameter] public string Text { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string> TextChanged { get; set; }

    private string text
    {
        get => Text;
        set => TextChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
    }
}
```

Assuming my EditForm is defined as below, how can I make the FieldChanged event fire for all field changes?

```cs
<EditForm EditContext="Context">
    <FieldListener></FieldListener>
    <p>Default text:</p>
    <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="Model.Text"></InputText>
    <p>Custom text with custom name binding:</p>
    <CustomEditor2 @bind-Text="Model.Text3"></CustomEditor2>
</EditForm>
```

It is worth noting that all field changes still make it to the Model, the FieldChanged event just doesn't always fire.

If helpful, here is a test project with a basic form to reproduce this: https://github.com/ThatFlashCat/CustomEditContextBindValue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<InputText>` contains the officially defined **class**, **value**, and **onchange**. But your custom component only contains `input` and `value`. This the source code of [InputText](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c42d1a3858906cd372eb787697f00c89ef2cde55/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/InputText.cs) (has been compiled).

[image]

You can trigger the change event by inheriting `InputText`.

In CustomEditor.razor.

```
@inherits InputText
<input class="form-control"  @bind="CurrentValueAsString"  />

@code {

}
```

This value `CurrentValueAsString` is a built-in context value. It can automatically assign the value of model.

Then I pass the change the value of CustomEditor.

[image]

And this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#built-in-forms-components) you can refer to.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I had a complicated component with dynamically generated checkboxes that bound to two separate lists. Switching the `<input type="checkbox" />` to `<InputCheckBox />` fixed the issue.